# how to select all checkbox in custom listview from activity in android

Tags: android, checkbox, custom-lists

I have a custom listview which content two textview and one checkbox. When checkbox is checked then id is stored in the database and if unchecked then id is removed from database. But I want to select all checkboxes and store all ids into database or uncheck all checkboxes and remove all ids from database. What exactly i have to implement for this. please help me this is my adapter code

```
public class InviteListAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "GroupEditMemberListAdapter";

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ViewHolder holder;
private List<FriendItem> list;
private Context context;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
MessageSendingActivity msg = new MessageSendingActivity();
private String groupId;
SqliteHandle sqhandle;
//private String adminId;
int total_contacts=0;
String f_id;
int flag=0;
String chetimeslot;
ArrayList<String> currentList = new ArrayList<String>();
public static final String DELETE_MEMBER = "2";
public static final String ADD_MEMBER = "1";

public InviteListAdapter2(Context context, List<FriendItem> list, String groupId, String adminId) {
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.list = list;
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
    this.groupId = groupId;
    //this.adminId = adminId;
}   

public ArrayList<String> getChekedItem()
{
    if(currentList!=null)
    return this.currentList;
    else return null;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return list.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

public void refresh(List<FriendItem> list) {
    this.list = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public List<FriendItem> getList() {
    return list;
}

View hView;

ArrayList<CheckedItem> checkbox_timeslot = new ArrayList<CheckedItem>();
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    hView = convertView;

    final FriendItem item = list.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        hView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friendlistitem, null);
        holder.nameTextView         = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.friend_name_text);
        holder.statusTextView       = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.friend_count_text);
        holder.userImageView        = (ImageView) hView.findViewById(R.id.friend_image);
        holder.checkBox             = (CheckBox) hView.findViewById(R.id.chekbox);

        hView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) hView.getTag();
    }

    try {
            holder.nameTextView.setText(""+item.getName() + " " +item.getLname());
            holder.statusTextView.setText(""+item.getContacts());

            String path = "http://www.gbggoa.org/testproject/four/images/pic.jpg";
            path = Constant.URL  + item.getImage();
            imageLoader.displayImage(path, holder.userImageView);

            if(item.getId().equals(Sessions.getUserId(context)))
            {
                holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else
            {
                holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if(item.isChecked())
            {
                holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);

                if(item.getId().equals(Sessions.getUserId(context)))
                {
                    hView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_list_gray);
                }
                else
                {
                    hView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_list_green);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
                hView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_list);
            }   

            holder.checkBox.setTag(position);
            holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return hView;
}   

class ViewHolder
{   
    TextView nameTextView, statusTextView;
    ImageView userImageView;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}

protected void showToast(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(context, ""+message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

protected void showToastLong(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(context, ""+message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}   

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    final int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
    String f_id=list.get(position).getId();
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chekbox);
    sqhandle=new SqliteHandle(context); 
    final boolean isChecked = checkBox.isChecked();
    int total=sqhandle.getCheckedCount();                       
    checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if(isChecked)
    {
        total_contacts = total_contacts + Integer.parseInt(list.get(position).getContacts());
        sqhandle.changeCheck("1", f_id);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Selected Contacts: "+total_contacts, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    else
    {
        sqhandle.changeCheck("0", f_id);
        total_contacts = total_contacts - Integer.parseInt(list.get(position).getContacts());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Selected Contacts: "+total_contacts, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    sqhandle.close();
    checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    list.get(position).setChecked(isChecked);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an ArrayList to store your Items Ids

```
ArrayList<Integer> tcontact = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 if(isChecked)
    {
         tcontact.add(Integer.parseInt(list.get(position).getContacts()))
        sqhandle.changeCheck("1", f_id);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Selected Contacts: "+total_contacts, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    else
    {
      for(int i=0;i<tcontact.size;i++) {
      if(tcontact.get(i) == Integer.parseInt(list.get(position).getContacts())) {
      tcontact.remove(i);
      sqhandle.changeCheck("0", f_id);

        Toast.makeText(context, "Selected Contacts: "+total_contacts, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}}
```

Comment: I have to add another checkbox that will check all other checkboxes in the listview. and where to add that checkbox? In my activity layout or adapter layout?

Comment: It's simply an ArrayList which is a Collection to store your clicked items

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

1. Add one checkbox on top of listview in your activity layout. For example a checkbox with id `chkall`.
2. Add one boolean flag called `checkedAll` in your adapter class `InviteListAdapter2` with getter & setter.
3. Create to add/remove from database as follow:

   ```
   public void modifyFriends(List<FriendItem> fList, boolean checkedAll){
       String checkStatus = "0";   
       if(checkedAll){
           checkStatus = "1";
       }
       //sql code to change check status in database for all friends
   }
   ```
4. Change `getView()` your adapter code little bit as follow:

   ```
   if(item.isChecked() || checkedAll)
       {
           holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);

           if(item.getId().equals(Sessions.getUserId(context)))
           {
               hView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_list_gray);
           }
           else
           {
               hView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_list_green);
           }
       }
       else
       {
           holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
           hView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_list);
       }
   ```
5. On click of `chkall` checkbox, do following:

   ```
       if(checked){
           inviteListAdapter2.setCheckedAll(true);
           modifyFriends(friendsList, true); //call a db helper method to change reflect check status in db
       }else{
           inviteListAdapter2.setCheckedAll(false);
           modifyFriends(friendsList, false); //call a db helper method to change reflect check status in db
       }
       inviteListAdapter2.notifyDatasetChaged();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

nAmDev,

I hear what you're saying about adding a checkbox to handle a user event signifying that the user wants to set all of the items' checkboxes to selected when the "Check All" checkbox is checked, or unselect all of the list items' checkboxes when the "Check All" checkbox is unchecked, or cleared.

So, to do this, yes, you would need to add a "Check all" checkbox, or possibly a actionbar menu item, to give the user a way to execute checking all of the items in the list.

In the click event handler for the "Check All" control, you would then get a reference to the list, or use the ArrayList that Nadir B described, and use that to loop through and check each item.

I am not sure if there is a way to create a reference to the list, and then do something similar to myList.SelectAll, or myList.CheckAll.

If not, and you want to do something similar to that, you could extend ListView and create your own CheckAll or SelectAll method, in which you would then just get a collection of the list items, and set each one to checked.